# How do I prevent Visual Studio 2017 build from duplicating content files in output directory on build?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, project

My goal is to prevent duplication while maintaining a desired layout.

So, I have a project (*C#/.Net462/ VS15-2017*) that references some third party DLLs.  For *reasons* I found it best to package these files along with my application, and reference the files in the app.config using the  directives.

For more *reasons* I decided to put these assemblies (.dll files) into my project as **content** that **copies when newer**.

**Project layout** looks something like below:

```
SexyApp                                  <-project
   References
       third.party.dll
   Images                                <-fluff
       sexy.png
   Lib                                   <-folder
       x86Arch                           <-folder
          third.party.dll                <-third party assembly (content, copy when newer)
          ru                             <-localized folder
             third.party.resource.dll    <-resource assembly (content, copy when newer)
   app.config
   sexy.cs
```

**Release output** looks something like this

```
bin
   Release
      sexy.exe
      sexy.config
      Images
         sexy.png
      third.party.dll                     <-This seems like a duplicate
      ru                                  <-This seems like a duplicate
         third.party.resource.dll         <-This seems like a duplicate
      Lib                                 <-This is what I want
         x86Arch                          <-This is what I want
            third.party.dll               <-This is what I want
            ru                            <-This is what I want
               third.party.resource.dll   <-This is what I want
```

**Desired output**

```
bin
   Release
      sexy.exe
      sexy.config
      Images
         sexy.png
      Lib                                    <-This is what I want
         x86Arch                             <-This is what I want
            third.party.dll                  <-This is what I want
            ru                               <-This is what I want
               third.party.resource.dll      <-This is what I want
```

**What I've tried**

- Build action none, copy when newer.  Still duplicates the files.
- Build action content, do not copy.  Copies them to the wrong location.
- References of the DLLs had copy local set to true.  Setting this to false didn't change the outcome.

**Edit:**
   Build path is simply 'bin\Release\'
   Reference to x86 was a folder... x86 version of the third party assemblies.

Comment: Where is the x86 folder? I have not seen it in the Release output and Desired output. Is `third.party.dll` file the same file under the reference node and under the x86 folder? How did you get those duplicate files, are you clean the solution before build, or any other operations? Can not reproduce this issue based on your Project layout. If possible, please share a small sample to us so that we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: MSBuild uses both `None` and `Content` items as an input for the `ResolveAssemblyReferences` task, so if you reference the assemblies, it may find these items as well. You may be able to set `Private="false"` on the `Content` items as well but without a reproducible example and/or the .csproj file, we probably can't help you more.

Comment: Sorry, still can not reproduce this issue, the duplicate file `third.party.dll` under the release folder, you can set the reference `copy local` to false. But the duplicate file  third.party.resource.dll under the ru folder, I can not reproduce it, I have not had it on my side. You should really share us a reproducible example sample.

Comment: Here's what I've found and how I solved it.
No matter what I set, it copies the reference over.  And, the software does indeed need those dlls.  But, I was also copying them over, so it didn't need to copy them.
I edited the csproj file, adding TARGET COPY SOURCEFILES for the dlls I wanted.  I did then in the before build space, and still copied them to a sub directory.  Then, the MSBuild stopped copying them over (not sure if it's still disregarding the settings/suggestions).
My takeaway is that it might copy them if it know they are needed, & doesn't know that they are copied another way.

Comment: Also noticed the project is targeting .Net 4.6.2, but the MSBuild log is showing that it's using 4.6.1 tools along with 4.6.2 tools.  This may be related, or it may be some unseen magic. It's specifically using 4.6.1 resgen.
I'd like to be able to provide a sample. This solution has twenty-some projects.  Was thinking I'd have someone remote in, & I could demonstrate with other dlls that I haven't moved to a subfolder yet. Not sure if I could provide a simple example.
Regardless, thanks for your responses, and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In the project file there will be a reference to the third.party.dll as well as a content entry for it.  The content entry is what's copying it to the subdirectory you desire.  In VS set it to "copy local false" or edit the project file in notepad and set false for the reference.

```
<Content Include="third.party.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Reference Include="third.party.dll">
  <Private>false</Private>
</Reference>
```

Even though you say you've tried setting the copy local to false, I know it will honour that.  For the file to be coming through anyway suggests to me a you have another component that references "third.party.dll" and it's set to copy local so it will bring in the "third.party.dll" to the root of the output directory for you.

Incidentally, you're fighting the default behaviour of both msbuild and .net by placing the 3rd party assemblies in a sub folder.  Your application will require a config file with probe paths set that you will need to maintain or it won't work.  Then if someone else adds a component that depends on "third.party.dll" then you'll be back to square one trying to hack it out of the bin folder.  Unless you have a compelling reason to use subfolders then don't - it's a headache you can live without.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

What you've got is fighting the default behaviour of msbuild as well as adding unnecessary complexity to your application.

Anything you place in a subfolder will need to have a corresponding probe path entry in the configuration file.  You will have to maintain that so any changes to add other folders will have additional maintenance overhead.  This will impede automated testing of unit and integration tests.

Additionally, you will need to go to additional effort to suppress the presence of the same assembly in multiple directories.  This will need to be managed and maintained going forward and it will repeatedly trip you up.

This is all overhead you can remove if you simply accept the bin folder as the location where all the assemblies end up and don't try to interfere with it.

Take it from someone who has just done the opposite of what you're trying to do because of all the problems it caused.